# VBA refresh form

Tags: vba, forms, refresh, progress

I have a simple progress bar. I want to fill it when I make iteration through my loop, but I only see my form with 0 and 100 progress value, so it doesn't refresh during the loop. How can I achieve the runtime refreshment? Thank you!

```
Sub test()
UserForm1.Show (False)
DoEvents

For i = 1 To 700
    For j = 1 To 5000
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = 100 * i / 700 & "% Completed"
        UserForm1.Bar.Width = 200 * i / 700 '200 - width of the bar
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: try DoEvents in a loop. And take a look here [UserForm.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) in a spare time

Comment: Your `DoEvents` has to be inside the loop, not before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the `DoEvents` in the wrong place. Try it like this.

```
Sub test()
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

For i = 1 To 700
    For j = 1 To 5000
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = 100 * i / 700 & "% Completed"
        UserForm1.Bar.Width = 200 * i / 700 '200 - width of the bar
        DoEvents
    Next
Next

End Sub
```